# Executing Oracle procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I connected my oracle database to visual studio and now I'm trying to execute procedure I created in my database.

I tried this:

```
           OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("BEGIN ADD_USER('"+txtName.Text+"','"+txtName2.Text+"',"+txtID.Text+"); END;" );

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

My procedure has 3 parameters : name, 2name, id. It works fine when I use this command in sqldeveloper, but I get error when I try it in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection("con string"))
{
    cn.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("ADD_USER");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = cn;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("YourSPParamName1", OracleDbType.{YourFieldTypeInDB}).Value = txtName.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("YourSPParamName2", OracleDbType.{YourFieldTypeInDB}).Value = txtName2.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("YourSPParamName3", OracleDbType.{YourFieldTypeInDB}).Value = txtID.Text;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Something like this should work.

Comment: @ktos1234 where I had a mistake ?

Comment: i didn't have Parameters.AddWithValue class, I had to use Parameters.Add

Answer (score 0):

Here's how It works for me:

```
        OracleConnectionStringBuilder sb = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder();
        sb.DataSource = "localhost";
        sb.UserID = "something";
        sb.Password = "pass";         
       OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(sb.ToString());
        conn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("ADD_USER");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = txtName.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("NAME2", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = txtName2.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("ID", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = txtID.Text;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```